# Script that change the HTML-content of another page?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

On my first page I have two input boxes and a button that will add the input to localStorage. When the data has been added I want to trigger an event that will write out the contents of localStorage on ANOTHER page. My problem is that my script can't find the element on the second page.

Code that adds the data to localStorage:

```
$("#submitLocal").click(function () {
  var key = inputKey.value;
  var value = inputValue.value;
  localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  if (newWindow == null || newWindow.closed) {
    newWindow = window.open("local.html", "localWindow");
  }
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage"));
});
```

I add the event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("storage", myFunc);
```

Which calls the function:

```
function myFunc(event) {
  document.getElementById("addInfo").innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    $("#addInfo").append(
      localStorage.key(i) +
        " " +
        localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) +
        "<br>"
    );
  }
}
```

Right now, the element "addInfo" is on the FIRST page, and the data in localStorage gets written out on the page. But how can I do to write it on the second page if it cant find the elements on that page?

Im new to stackoverflow so I hope I managed to describe the problem well enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per my undertanding to your question you are expecting the 1st page to manipulate the 2nd page. can you tell us more about it? does the page reloads from 1st page to 2nd page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ALWAYS helps to post relevant code. In this case what is `$("#submitLocal")` ? If it is a submit button in a form, use the form submit event and `preventDefault`!

Why dispatch events in an event?

Just use the one you are in and the load event in page2

main page

```
$("#myForm").on("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var key = inputKey.value;
  var value = inputValue.value;
  localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  if (newWindow == null || newWindow.closed) {
    newWindow = window.open("local.html", "localWindow");
  }
});
```

local.html

```
function myFunc(event) {
  $("#addInfo").empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    $("#addInfo").append(
      localStorage.key(i) +
        " " +
        localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) +
        "<br>"
    );
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load",myFunc)
```

Comment: Because the clickevent wouldnt be triggered without it for some reason. I searched a bit about it and it could be because some security setting in Google Chrome. However the dispatch fixed the problem so Im satisfied with that.

Comment: See update. There is no reason in the script you posted that would not react to a click. I cahnge the event handlder from click to on("click" and modified the DOM access to jQuery in the second script too

Comment: IF submitLocal is a submit button, then you need `$("#formID").on("submit", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ...` to stop the submission - that would be a reason the click did not work

Comment: Thanks a lot! The load eventListener fixed it. Deeply grateful!